# I can't see the videocapture

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to learn some image processing using openCV and i wrote a basic code but the "frame" windows won't show.I've tried installing on a separate computer but i get the same problem.
import cv2

```
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

        while (True):
          ret, frame = cap.read()
          gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
          cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

      cap.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Move your `if` 2 columns right, and your `break` 4 columns right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you added your if statement is outside the while loop and therefore can never be checked. It should have thrown a different error however if that was the case. Your camera might be detected but not working. Try using it like a traditional webcam on another program like camera or photobooth to help troubleshoot the issue.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I checked the leptop's webcam and another webcam,also i've tried to change the camera but it;s still the same.I think it's from pyton,i've installed 3.7.7.
Thank you for your time tho.